# detecting network connectivity in blackberry using phonegap

Tags: cordova, blackberry, network-programming

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady(), false);
function onDeviceReady() {
var networkState = navigator.network.connection.type;
        alert(networkState );
}
```

The above code in phonegap doesnot have any effect on blackberry,But works well for androin and ios.

In my config.xml file i have the following:

```
<plugin name="NetworkStatus"  value="org.apache.cordova.network.Network"/>

                                  and also

<preference name="phonegap-version" value="2.1.0" />
```

In my main file i have the follwing script tag :

```
<script src="phonegap.js" type="application/x-javascript" 
charset="utf-8"></script>
```

But still i get "undefined" in alert !! 
I need some help on detecting internet connectivity in blackberry using phonegap !!

Comment: there are HTML5 APIs available for BB10 and playbook. Do you want for lower versions as well?

Comment: ya i need for blackberry smartphones with OS > 5.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why dont you try to make an ajax call to your server and if u get the response display "internet connection available" or else display "no internet connection" in the error of ajax.